# How to talk to an Arduino using Java?

Tags: java, arduino

How do I talk to an Arduino using Java?

I need it for my [CNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_control) project. It seems this chunk of code works, but I don't know how to use it. See Stack Overflow question *[Control an Arduino with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023640)*.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I like your question. It helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at page *[Arduino and Java](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Java)*. It talks about Java/Arduino serial communication.

However, to control an Arduino with [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), you have to program it to accept commands and send commands to it with Java. You can't directly control it with Java, because Arduino uses [Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29), that is a C-like language.

Comment: Why people don't like this question?

Comment: From the Stack Overflow FAQs: `Questions that are not a good fit for this site may be voted closed by experienced community members. Closed questions cannot be answered, but are eligible for improvement (and eventual re-opening) through editing, voting, and commenting. See How to Ask for guidance on editing your question to improve it`. You should read them before posting :)

Comment: I didn't downvote the question, but I think the reason it's getting downvoted is that you've already got a link to an answer, and yet you're asking the same question. It's almost as redundant-looking as  posting a question that asks how to post a question.